# php5-suhosin Broken Installation

Tags: php

Hi i get the following error when trying to install, have you any idea how to fix?

```
apt-get install php5-suhosin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-suhosin : Depends: phpapi-20090626
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I get the following error in my apache2 error log

```
[Mon May 07 21:43:15 2012] [error] [client ip] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/suhosin.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/suhosin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Which Linux distribution and version are you using?

Comment: Debian squeeze  3.2.0-1-amd64

Answer (score 2):

php5-suhosin package is broken in Debian now. This is the bug report about suhosin problem:

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=668739